# Scope of function prototypes in c file instead of header

Tags: c, scope

Apologies if this question has been asked before (I only found variants to this question on SO, but not the exact one)

My question is regarding scope w.r.t where the function prototype is defined.

Assume we have 3 files : `test.h`, `test.c`, `main.c`

`main.c` and `test.c` both includes `test.h`

**test.c**:

```
int f2(int b); // function prototype (local)

int x=0;
// public function
int f1(int a){
 return a*5;      
}
// local function
int f2(int b){
 return b*10;
}
```

**test.h**:

```
int f1(int a);
```

**main.c**:

```
#include "test.h"
int x=1;
int main(){
    printf("%d \n", f1(5));
    printf("%d \n", f2(5));
    return 0;
}
```

My question is:

- Can `main.c` access `f2()` which is implemented and prototype declared inside `test.c`
- Can `main.c` access `f1()`? or does it need to be declared as `extern`
- Does `main.c` have access to the `x` global variable inside `test.c`? Will it conflict with the global variable `x` (same name) defined in `main.c`?
- To gain local scope is it mandatory to use `static` keyword?
- Can static functions access global variables (static/non-static) defined in the same `.c` file ?

Answer (score 3):

In answering your questions, I suppose that the two .c sources are compiled and linked together into one program.

> - Can `main.c` access `f2()` which is implemented and prototype declared inside `test2.c`

Modern C does not permit calls to functions that have no declaration in scope, but K&R C did permit such calls, and most implementations do still allow them.  Moreover, `main.c` could declare the function itself and then call it.

> - Can `main.c` access `f1()`? or does it need to be declared as `extern`

Functions have external linkage by default.  Accordingly, `extern` is the default for function declarations.  You may explicitly specify `extern`, but that's redundant.

> - Does `main.c` have access to the `x` global variable inside `test.c`? Will it conflict with the global variable `x` (same name) defined in
>     main.c?

Yes and no.  It is *erroneous* for one program to contain two definitions of the same identifier with external linkage, and both your declarations of `x` do indeed constitute definitions, and both do indeed (by default) have external linkage.

However, some implementations will merge those into one variable, others will refuse to link the program, and others might even maintain separate `x` variables.

The right way to declare a variable that is shared across source files, by the way, is for each file to declare it, `extern`, but for exactly one to initialize it.  Usually, the `extern` declarations without initializer would go into a header file, and a single declaration with an initializer (which makes it a definition) would go into one .c file.  Example:

---

**test.h**

```
extern int x; // _with_ extern, _without_ initializer
```

---

**test.c**

```
#include "test.h"
int x = 0;  // 'extern' is optional here
```

---

**main.c**

```
#include "test.h"
// no further declaration of x here
```

---

> - To gain local scope is it mandatory to use `static` keyword?

The `static` and `extern` keywords are about *linkage*, not scope.  Linkage has to do with which code can access which objects and functions.  Scope is about which code can see which *declarations*.  Although they sound similar, these are in fact quite distinct concepts, because the same object or function can be declared multiple times.  In fact, that's routine -- it's one of the primary purposes served by header files.

> - Can static functions access global variables (static/non-static) defined in the same `.c` file ?

Yes, where I interpret "global" to mean "declared at file scope".  C does not have a concept of global variables *per se*, but objects declared outside any function exist for the whole duration of the program.  Those with external linkage can be accessed from any code in the program where declarations of their identifiers are in scope.  Those with internal linkage (declared by the `static` keyword) can be accessed only from within the same translation unit, which roughly means the same .c file.

It is also possible for an object to have *no* linkage.  This is the case for objects declared inside functions.

Comment: I understand the answer is compiler/linker specific. I'm compiling for the MSP430 platform, so assume the msp-gcc compiler (C89). But I would like to know the behaviour latest standard GCC compiler and Gnu tools (assuming set to C89). So for the first question - if i compile and run the above, will it produce a compiler/linker/runtime error/warning ?

Comment: @Rosh, if what you are taking away is that the answer is compiler-specific, then you are missing the point: write conforming code, so that its behavior is *not* compiler specific.  It is not that hard to do.  As for GCC's behavior with respect to any of these questions, have you not considered trying it out for yourself?  It turns out, though, that GCC is among the compilers that still accepts implicit function declarations.  It will emit a warning about them under many combinations of options, and if you wish, you can cause that to be emitted as an error instead.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, but accidentally. A function with no declarator will default to `int` type, and its parameters will default to `int` type, and storage class will default to `extern`. Your function happens to already have those types. Thus, the declarator is not needed, strictly speaking (though it is a very bad practice to not use one). However, this has apparently been made illegal in C99, and if you are using C99 semantics, you should get an error; otherwise it is just a warning (`-Wimplicit-function-declaration`).

2) As said above, the lack of storage class specifier in the `test.h` declarator will implicitly declare `f1` as extern. All is well.

3) The linker will raise an error regarding duplicate identifier. If you use `extern int x;` (with no initialisation), it works. Variables don't get implicit declarations; if you just attempt to use `x` in `main.c` without the above declaration, you will get an error regarding use of an undeclared variable.

4) `static` means several different things. I assume the question is about static functions. This only restricts the visibility of the function to the current compilation unit; there is no other effect.

5) As noted above, making a function static only affects what can access *it*, not what *it* can access.

Comment: In strict C99 or later, functions do not default to anything; they must be declared (or defined) before they are used.

Comment: I think i'm more interested in C89 behaviour, but thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

> Can main.c access f2() which is implemented and prototype declared inside test2.c

The function `f2` will be taken as a default function which has return value of int and parameters `int` if any. However, if you use different parameters, it will give an error.

From C99 onwards, the default function is not applicable and this will give an error.

> Can main.c access f1()? or does it need to be declared as extern

Yes, it can access f1() as you have included `test.h` However you also need to compile `test.c` and give both files to the linker.

`f1()` declaration in `test.h` does not need to be declared as extern. By default, a function declaration is extern.

> Does main.c have access to the x global variable inside test.c? Will it conflict with the global variable x (same name) defined in main.c?

You need to link the variables together. Once you do you will get a linker error for this.

> To gain local scope is it mandatory to use static keyword?

If the variable is declared outside a function, it is global. To make it local scope you need to specifically use the static keyword.

> Can static functions access global variables (static/non-static) defined in the same .c file ?

Yes

Comment: In C90, the assumed return type of a function was indeed `int`, but nothing was assumed about the arguments except that they were subject to default argument promotion rules.  C99 and above does not, strictly, allow functions to be used before they are declared (or defined).

Comment: So, in practice an `int` or `int, int` or `char` argument is OK, but not `float`

Comment: Nope.  A `float` will be promoted to `double`, that's all.  You can pass `char *` and `struct Anything *` and so on too.  Further, the compiler isn't required to check your calls for consistency.  If you use an explicit function declaration like `extern int function();` then that has no prototype and any arguments are default promoted and there's no guarantee the compiler will cross-check different calls for consistency.  The C99 rules require a declaration; they don't require a prototype declaration, though.  You should tell your compiler to require strict prototype declarations if possible.

Comment: Hi, so I don't understand the first answer. what is a 'default function' ? My question is if main() can call f2(), even though it can't see the function declaration, as it's not in the test.h header file. will this return a compiler / linker / runtime error/warning ?

Comment: @Rosh - In C89 and before, if there was no declaration the compiler would implicitly assume that the function will return an `int`. A warning may be given based on your flags.